# How do I Write an overloaded version of iquote

Tags: java, methods

My assignment is to write an overloaded version of `iquote()`, a method that displays the type of its argument and its argument enclosed in double quotation marks. I am asked to write three versions: one for `int` argument, one for a `double` argument and one for a `String` argument. I am not required to supply an application part.

This is what i have so far, it will compile however a get an error message: `Could not find or load main class assign61`

Could someone please help me with this code...

```
public class assign61 {
     public void iquote(String s){
        return sQuote;
        System.out.println( "sQuote\" );" 
    }
    public void iquote(int n){
        return iQuote;
        System.out.println( "sQuote\" );" 
    }       
    public void iquote(double d){
        return iQuote;
        System.out.println( "sQuote\" );"          
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just compile it, or using the run button?

Comment: What is the name of this file? Is it assign61.java? Have you made sure that capitalization and spelling are correct?

Comment: Also, you'll want to show the complete error message, since this is what we must focus our attention on.

Comment: yes I compiled it. and the name of the file is assign61.java i did try that

Comment: @user1467814 that code can't compile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can't be compiling properly because there are errors in it. Therefore, if it wont compile, it can't be run.

There are a few changes that you need to make...

```
public class assign61 {

    public assign61(){
        iquote("Test");
        iquote("123");
        iquote("5.678");
        }

    public void iquote(String s){
        System.out.println("sQuote:" + s);
    }
    public void iquote(int n){
        System.out.println("iQuote:" + n);
    }       
    public void iquote(double d){
        System.out.println("dQuote:" + d);       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new assign61();
    }

}
```

Basically this is what needed to change...

1. You want to output the value, so this is added to the end of the `System.out.println()` lines by the `+` symbol.
2. You had `return` statements in your methods, but they aren't what you want to use. `return` is for returning a value to the code that called the method - they aren't for outputting a value to the command prompt.
3. Because of your `return` statements, they also would have prevented your code from compiling because you had them written *before* your `System.out.println()` statements instead of *after* them. `return` can't have anything written after it in the code. Also, to use `return` statements, you would need to change your methods to be `public int iQuote(int n)` instead of using the `void` statement, so it knows what type of data you'll be returning from the method
4. I have added a constructor method `assign61` which has some test code in it to show that your other methods work correctly. I have also added the `main` method so that you can run your code.

I hope this helps you to understand a little more. Try making some of the changes suggested above, then compile your code. Once it compiles correctly, you will be able to run it. Then you can come back to us with any further problems.

Comment: I compile with all those changes you advice however I got an error message                                                           C:\cs151\Assignment6> javac assign61.java
assign61.java:3: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println("sQuote:" + s);"
                                          ^
assign61.java:6: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println("iQuote:" + n);"
                                          ^
assign61.java:9: error: unclosed string literal
        System.out.println("dQuote:" + d);"
                                          ^

Comment: I just made a code change - I noticed some incorrect quotes - try again now

Comment: I edited the code in my answer above - see my main answer and it has the edited code change

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class assign61, please define the main method as
:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: In your question you said you didn't need application code, so are you actually supposed to run your code, so I assumed that maybe you just gave your code to the teacher just like you posted? If you need to run it yourself, I have edited my answer to include the constructor and main methods that you will need to make a runnable application.

Comment: No problems. If you have an answer that works, please remember to 'tick' the answer so that everyone else knows that the problem has been solved, and to thank the user for helping you.

Answer (score 1):

```
Could not find or load main class assign61
```

I think the most probable reason might be you didn't name the file right as assign61.java (BTW, you should capitalize the class name, as the convention suggests.)

Also at this time, to run you class, at least you should have a main method. A convenient way for java is to create a main method in this class.

Comment: Name of the class it's a problem, still not the problem to load it. Have you tried to compile the code?